# Entity Framework generated code to linked Silverlight project does not include function imports

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

1. I am experimenting with a Silverlight MVVM (using MEF) application with the following architecture: I have a n-tier Silverlight solution. One of the projects is a .NET project which contains my Entity Data Model object. Let's call this project MySqlData
2. I successfully generate code from an existing database.
3. From MySQLData EDMX Model Browser, I add a stored procedure using a function import which also creates a complex type.
4. I add Code Generation items to the project and end up with MySqlData.tt and MySqlData.Context.tt
5. My new function import and complex type successfully appear in MySqlData.tt and MySqlData.Context.tt after clicking Run Custom Tool.(I'm happy!)
6. I also add WCF RIA domain services class to MySqlData project since I'm working with a Silverlight application.
7. Under the same solution, I go to a Silverlight project called, MyInfrastructure, and click the properties. In the WCF RIA Service Link option under the Silverlight Build Options I select my MySqlData project.
8. When I build the MyInfrastructure project I can see the generated class MySqlData.g.cs.
9. **Now here's the problem** (thanks for your patience): The generated code MySqlData.g.cs does not have any reference to my new Function Import and the new Complex Type created in the MySqlData project. As a matter of fact the Domain Service class does not show any reference to the new complex type, consequently it will not generate the expected code to the MyInfrastructure project. I tried something else other than a complex type, say a stored proc that just returns a string. Still no good. I also tried creating a partial DomainService class and had no good result either.
10. What can I do to force the functions imports and the like to show up on the generated code in another project. I'm hoping not to have to resort to manual intervention to make these things happen otherwise every time a regenerate code via custom tool I'll have to do something manually.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Entity Framework 4.3.1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem:

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

Firstly, it is not necessary to use template text to generate .tt files here because the generated code is created when I create the WCF RIA Service reference in the Silverlight class library. In the case of my example it's called MyInfrastructure.

To ensure the generated code showed my new stored procedure and the complex type I created, I had to create a partial Domain Services class with the following content:

```
namespace MySqlData
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework;


    public partial class MySqlDataDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MySqlDataEntities>
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.Query]
        public IQueryable<JournalViewItem> GetJournalViewItems()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.GetJournalViewItems().AsQueryable();
        }

    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(JournalViewItemMetadata))]
    public partial class JournalViewItem
    {

        internal sealed class JournalViewItemMetadata
        {
            public JournalViewItemMetadata() { }

            [Key]
            public int JournalItemId { get; set; }
        }
    }


}
```

There were two important things that helped me:

I had to add this annotation to the function import:

```
[System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.Query]
```

I also had to create code below solve error relating to missing key with JournalViewItem complex type:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(JournalViewItemMetadata))]
    public partial class JournalViewItem
    {

        internal sealed class JournalViewItemMetadata
        {
            public JournalViewItemMetadata() { }

            [Key]
            public int JournalItemId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I hope this can help someone.